# Firebase phone auth is not working even though it worked before

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using phone firebase auth for my authentication, It worked as I developed my flutter app
for like 5 months or more, only yesterday it stopped working, I have tried several attempts to sign in using phone auth and it worked once then returned this error again. I have searched through the internet tried every solution I find and none worked.

```
W/System  ( 5394): A resource failed to call end. 
W/FirebaseAuth( 5394): [FirebaseAuthFallback:] App hash will not be appended to the request.
W/FirebaseAuth( 5394): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS auto-retrieval unavailable; SmsRetriever will not start.
W/System  ( 5394): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/FirebaseAuth( 5394): [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a limit for the number of sms you can recieve from firebase to one device

> To prevent abuse, Firebase enforces a limit on the number of SMS messages that can be sent to a single phone number within a period of time. If you exceed this limit, phone number verification requests might be throttled. If you encounter this issue during development, use a different phone number for testing, or try the request again later

Please check this for reference
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth